# VB.NET Access connection string with credentials

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to connect into an Access 2010 database via a network share and I want to supply the credentials.  The below string is not working; it brings back a "Could not find installable ISAM" error.

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\192.168.xx.xx\Custom Tools\Tracker.accdb;Uid=admin;Pwd=;"
```

Comment: Do you have the ACE database provider installed?

Comment: Well, this works fine if I take the username/pw part out.  If I open up the share first and authenticate, then just connect in without the UID/PW, it opens and displays with no issues.  But I want to always authenticate first so I don't have to worry about it later.

Comment: The .accdb file format does not support User-Level Security (ULS), so supplying a username and password in the connection string really doesn't make any sense. If you need credentials to access the server share you will probably need to establish a connection to the server before you try and connect to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to force server authentication if your computers are not on a domain.  For example, if your MSAccess DB is on a P2P network or a server that is not on your domain.

In that case, one simple option is to require each user to have a drive mapped to your \192.168.xx.xx server (mentioned above).  That will force authentication when the user logs-in to a PC.